# How to enter variables in function to use in MySQL prepared statements?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I want to create a function to select data from database, but the problem is that I don't know how to enter types variables and variables inside my function.  So is there any way to do that?

```
$is ='ssi';
$vars ='$product_type,$product_name,$product_price';
function dj_insert($stmt,$is,$vars)
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$is,$vars);
}
dj_insert($is,$vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables need to be in an array, so define an array:

```
$vars = [$product_type, $product_name, $product_price];
```

Or explode the string if needed:

```
//notice double " not single ' quotes for variables
$vars = "$product_type,$product_name,$product_price";
$vars = explode(',', $vars);
```

Then just use [Argument unpacking via `...`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat):

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $is, ...$vars);
```

You might want to check that you have the same number of types and variables first:

```
if(strlen($is) !== count($vars)) {
    return false; //throw exception or something
}
```

Also see that you need to pass in a valid statement object:

```
dj_insert($stmt, $is, $vars);
```

Comment: please can you write for me the whole function ?

Comment: thanks what said me i did it before the problem is with the first var how can i enter it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by first var?  You need to explain exactly what you don't understand with examples.

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $is, ...$vars); ??? why did you put these points before $vars?

Comment: There is a link just before that that explains what it does.  It unpacks an array into individual vars to pass to the function.

Comment: why didn't you put an answer directly as a function why do you wont to kill me? hhhh